# Strange behaviour of Tomcat 8.0.32: sometimes it ignores cookies. Can it be somehow debugged?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, cookies, tomcat8

There is a very weird problem with our Tomcat 8.0.32 installed under Ubuntu 16.x.

This problem starts to happen accidentally and exists until tomcat server restart (so it is reproducible after it begins happen).

What happens, is that some of the requests send by timer from JS application with proper `cookie: JSESSIONID=` value are improperly processed: the Tomcat can not find `Session` object for it (from `Spring MVC` layer it means, that user is not authenticated). All requests with **the same** JSESSIONID being sent before this broken request, and all requests being send after (again with the same value of session id) - they all work fine!

We also certainly see that all headers in that request are correct (they are printed out by our application in some Filter), but `Session` object is not restored.

So basically it sounds like under some circumstances the Tomcat starts ignoring JSESSIONID from the requests sent via redirect from another server. And again, this does not happen always, only after some time of web-application life.

I will not provide any code here or configuration settings. First, because it looks like the poor Tomcat problem, second, because configuration is standard (out of the box after apt-install).

**My question is**: how can we configure the Tomcat in order to log all operations related to the JSESSIONID processing? Like that it finds session for the given ID, or does not and so on.

---

UPD: This never happens with more newer version of Tomcat 8.5.5. But due to some reasons it can not be updated on that particular server. My current goal is to collect evidences about this behaviour to be sure that it is a bug, or some strange default configuration that tomcat installation.

Comment: I am not so familiar with logging of Tomcat HTTP requests.  Typically I have my Java servers behind a reverse proxy such as nginx.  First look what Tomcat can do and if it would not be sufficient, consider putting nginx (or another reverse proxy) in between to provide the logging.

Comment: Or, do you mean that nginx proxy, staying behing the Tomcat, can somehow process sessions?

Comment: You would put the Tomcat behind the nginx, not the other way around. Tomcat has to process its own sessions. Though by putting nginx in the middle, you could use it to have enhanced logging. I am not an expert in the matter though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html
to enable debug logging for part of Tomcat's internals, you should configure both the appropriate logger(s) and the appropriate handler(s) to use the FINEST or ALL level. e.g.:

```
org.apache.catalina.session.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
```

Comment: Hi @AntonMalyshev. Thanks for you reply. Where should I place this configurations? Into log4j.properties of my application or somewhere else?

Comment: `${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties`  or `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties`